# Cmake error: -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Tags: compiling, qt, cmake

I have an error when I run `cmake ..`. Could you please help me? Thanks so much

I want to build my project. I use `mkdir build`, `cd build/` and `cmake ..`.Then I got this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1314 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "5.12.8" from /usr/bin/qmake, this code
  requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jingsheng/src/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

After that, I check my QT version with `qmake --version`. Then I got:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.8 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Could you please help me, how could I do?

Comment: Which application are you trying to compile? Is it available somewhere online?

Comment: No, it is the project from my uni. We want to implement the robot motion planning using RRT connect. I want to extend the method of the basic RRT algorithm.

Comment: You can try to use the method from my answer below, but it may not work because of Qt4 EOL.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt4 packages are available from [third party PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4). You have to add it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install necessary development package

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev qt4-qmake qt4-dev-tools
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I try to do your command. After that, it has also the same error.

Comment: You have to try installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in VM to compile your application.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have already fixed this error with rebuild my project. Now it works. I don't get this error anymore. Have a nice day.